# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0 on running maven on JDK 18

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I have a maven application on running `./mvnw clean package` gives the following error

My maven wrapper is set 3.3.9

The maven wrapper.properties file has the distributionURL set as
`distributionUrl=https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/apache-maven/3.3.9/apache-maven-3.3.9-bin.zip`

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project resource-completed-apollo: Fatal error compiling: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Unable to make field private com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$DiscoveredProcessors com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoveredProcs accessible: module jdk.compiler does not "opens com.sun.tools.javac.processing" to unnamed module @7b80af04 -> [Help 1]
```

My Maven- JAVA setup

```
Apache Maven 3.8.5 (3599d3414f046de2324203b78ddcf9b5e4388aa0)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.8.5/libexec
Java version: 18.0.1, vendor: Homebrew, runtime: /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/18.0.1/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "12.3", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

POM File snippet used in the project, which includes the dependencies used in the project and also the repositories used

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
            <version>5.1</version>
        </dependency>       
        <!-- Spring boot related drivers -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Redis drivers 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>   -->
        <!-- JDBC Drivers  and Lombok driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.24</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- mongo db drivers -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongodb-driver-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Dependency for Graph QL and JSON Transformation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.leangen.graphql</groupId>
            <artifactId>spqr</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>       
        <!-- Dependency for String utility classes -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- KTP Java Utilities -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>kaplan.ktpa.api.inst</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-util-package</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0-RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>     
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-repo</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories> 
</project>
```

Need help in solving this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [module jdk.compiler does not "opens com.sun.tools.javac.processing" to unnamed module @4bae33a6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68330987/module-jdk-compiler-does-not-opens-com-sun-tools-javac-processing-to-unnamed-m)

Comment: First what does this means: `3.3.9` ? Using Maven 3.3.9 but. this contradicts what you've writting using Maven 3.8.5 ... furthermore please show the pom file ....

Comment: I updated my Java version to 18.0.1, with mvn using the 18 JDK, but still the error persists @SpaceTrucker

Comment: i am using a maven wrapper to build the application @khmarbaise

Comment: @ElvisFernandes "a maven wrapper" is too unspecific. Provide the exact details and config of the wrapper. Have you tried with maven directly without any wrapper?

Comment: Based on `module jdk.compiler` do you use `module-info.java` configuration? Please show this incl. pom file etc.